# I want to group time interval based on given tolerance in postgres sql(consider interval of 1 sec for for continuous time interval)

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

Below is a sample table with current output given.

```
select id,name,timeint,count(timeint) from sample1
group by id,name,timeint
order by name,timeint;


------current output------
id  name    timeint count
1   aaa   00:00:01  2
1   aaa   00:00:02  1
1   aaa   00:00:03  1
1   aaa   00:00:04  1
1   aaa   00:00:06  1
1   aaa   00:00:08  1
2   bbb   00:00:01  1
2   bbb   00:00:02  1
2   bbb   00:00:03  1
```

So the above output should be regrouped in such a manner that for same id and name , timeint with 1 
 sec tolerance should be considered as same. If timeint is in sequence group all together.

```
------expected output----
id  name   timeint  count
1   aaa    00:00:01 5
1   aaa    00:00:06 1
2   bbb    00:00:08 1
2   bbb    00:00:01 3
```

Help to solve this using recursive CTE?

Answer (score 1):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  You can use `lag()` to determine where the "islands" begin.  Then use a cumulative sum to assign an "island" grouping to each group.  Finally aggregate:

```
select id, name, min(timeint), sum(count)
from (select t.*,
             count(*) filter (where prev_ti < timetint - interval '1 second') over (partition by id, name order by timeint) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(timeint) over (partition by id, name order by timeint) as prev_ti
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by id, name, grp;
```